# regular expression in R: how to extract characters from a string

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector of strings each containing last and first name of one or more authors. I would like to extract the last names of each author in each string. What I know is that the name that comes first is always the last name of an author (the first author), and the last names of the other authors are everything that is between between a `;` and a `,`. For example, in the following string:

```
tutu <- "goulenok, tiphaine miquel; meune, christophe; gossec, laure; dougados, maxime; kahan, andre; allanore, yannick"
```

I would like to extract:

```
"goulenok" "meune" "gossec" "dougados" "kahan" "allanore"
```

The last name may include punctuation characters such as `'` or `-` but always be between a `;` and a `,`

Any idea?

Comment: Is your input all in one character string (suggested by your code), or is it a vector of strings (suggested by your question)?

Comment: it is a vector of strings actually. Thanks,

Comment: it is a vector of strings actually. I won't extract the same number of author names and I'd need to put them in a data.frame in order of appearance. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> sub(",.*$", "", strsplit(tutu, ";[ ]+")[[1]])
[1] "goulenok" "meune"    "gossec"   "dougados" "kahan"    "allanore"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses the gsubfn package:

```
library(gsubfn)

unlist(strapplyc(tutu, "(?:^|;) *([^,]+)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more blunt but also works:

```
sapply(unlist(lapply(strsplit(tutu, ";"), strsplit, ",")), "[", 1)
```