# Extracting first names in R

Tags: regex, r

Say I have a vector of peoples' names in my dataframe:

```
names <- c("Bernice Ingram", "Dianna Dean", "Philip Williamson", "Laurie Abbott",
           "Rochelle Price", "Arturo Fisher", "Enrique Newton", "Sarah Mann",
           "Darryl Graham", "Arthur Hoffman")
```

I want to create a vector with the first names. All I know about them is that they come first in the vector above and that they're followed by a space. In other words, this is what I'm looking for:

```
"Bernice" "Dianna"  "Philip" "Laurie" "Rochelle"
"Arturo"  "Enrique" "Sarah"  "Darryl" "Arthur"
```

I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326870/regular-expression-in-r-how-to-extract-characters-from-a-string), but the answers (especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14326920/1169233)) haven't helped much. So far, I've tried a couple of variations of function from the [`grep` family](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html), and the closest I could get to something useful was by running `strsplit(names, " ")` to separate first names and then `strsplit(names, " ")[[1]][1]` to get just the first name of the first person. I've been trying to tweak this last command to give me a whole vector of first names, to no avail.

Comment: This assumes that people have first names. [That is wrong](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122328/first-name-middle-name-last-name-why-not-full-name

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `sapply` to extract the first name:

```
> sapply(strsplit(names, " "), `[`, 1)
 [1] "Bernice"  "Dianna"   "Philip"   "Laurie"   "Rochelle" "Arturo"   "Enrique" 
 [8] "Sarah"    "Darryl"   "Arthur"
```

Some comments:

The above works just fine. To make it a bit more general you could change the `split` parameter in `strsplit` function from `" "` in `"\\s+"` which covers multiple spaces. Then you also could use `gsub` to extract directly everything before a space. This last approach will use only one function call and likely to be faster (but I haven't check with benchmark).

Answer (score 5):

For what you want, here's a pretty unorthodox way to do it:

```
read.table(text = names, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, fill = TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "Bernice"  "Dianna"   "Philip"   "Laurie"   "Rochelle" "Arturo"   "Enrique"  "Sarah"   
# [9] "Darryl"   "Arthur"
```

Comment: nice! and in case of someone having a second name I'd suggest to set `fill=T` :)

Comment: @Michele, Thanks. I *had* intended to do that, but forgot to do so when posting. Will update now.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
unlist(strsplit(names,' '))[seq(1,2*length(names),2)]
```

Assuming no first/last names have spaces in them.

Answer (score 3):

Using regexpr on `gsub`

```
> gsub("^(.*?)\\s.*", "\\1", names)
 [1] "Bernice"  "Dianna"   "Philip"   "Laurie"   "Rochelle" "Arturo"   "Enrique"  "Sarah"   
 [9] "Darryl"   "Arthur"
```

Comment: or `sub(' .*', '', names)`