# Separate "Name" into "FirstName" and "LastName" columns of data frame

Tags: r, strsplit

I am struggling to figure out how to take a single column of "Name" in a dataframe split it into two other columns of FistName and LastName within the same data frame. The challenge is that some of my Names have several last names.  Essentially, I want to take the first word (or element of the string) and put it in the FirstName columns, then put all following text (minus the space of course) into the LastName column.

This is my DataFrame "tteam"

```
NAME <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope-Douglas', 'Muhammad Arnab Halwai')
TITLE <- c("assistant", "manager", "assistant", "specialist")
tteam<- data.frame(NAME, TITLE)
```

My desired output would like this:

```
FirstName <- c("John", "Peter", "Jolie", "Muhammad")
LastName <- c("Doe", "Gynn", "Hope-Douglas", "Arnab Halwai")
tteamdesire <- data.frame(FirstName, LastName, TITLE)
```

I have tried the following code to create a new data frame of just names that allow me to extract the first names from the first column.  However, I am unable to put the last names into any order.

```
names <- tteam$NAME ##  puts full names into names vector
namesdf <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(names),' ',fixed=TRUE))) 
## splits out all names into a dataframe PROBLEM IS HERE!
```

Comment: I don't think you can get this one correct. Some people have several given names, some have several family names and then there is something called "middle name".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321673/extracting-first-names-in-r

Comment: I believe this post should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299978/splitting-a-string-on-the-first-space

Comment: Note that in the real world this is a pointless exercise - people have multiple first or last names, put their family names first and familar names second, or third, and I once heard of a Chinese student whose three-part name appeared in the student records database in all 6 possible permutations of A B C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `extract` from `tidyr`

```
 library(tidyr)
 extract(tteam, NAME, c("FirstName", "LastName"), "([^ ]+) (.*)")
 #  FirstName     LastName      TITLE
 #1      John          Doe  assistant
 #2     Peter         Gynn    manager
 #3     Jolie Hope-Douglas  assistant
 #4  Muhammad Arnab Halwai specialist
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all of the submissions.  Chose this answer because of its simplicity.  Works now.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
> firstname = sapply(strsplit(NAME, ' '), function(x) x[1])
> firstname 
[1] "John"     "Peter"    "Jolie"    "Muhammad"

> lastname = sapply(strsplit(NAME, ' '), function(x) x[length(x)])
> lastname
[1] "Doe"          "Gynn"         "Hope-Douglas" "Halwai"
```

or:

```
> ll = strsplit(NAME, ' ')
> 
> firstname = sapply(ll, function(x) x[1])
> lastname = sapply(ll, function(x) x[length(x)])
> 
> firstname
[1] "John"     "Peter"    "Jolie"    "Muhammad"
> lastname
[1] "Doe"          "Gynn"         "Hope-Douglas" "Halwai"
```

Comment: The last name in the list has a 'middle' name also. To avoid that I used x[length(x)].

Comment: Oops, I didn't see it, but in the tteamdesire, the middle name is also joined with the last name

Comment: Consider `str_split(NAME, " ", n=2)` from `stringr`

Answer (score 3):

**1) sub**

```
data.frame(FirstName = sub(" .*", "", tteam$NAME), 
           LastName = sub("^\\S* ", "", tteam$NAME),
           tteam[-1])
```

**2) gsubfn::read.pattern**  In the `NAME<-` we can omit `as.character` if its already character (as opposed to factor):

```
library(tteam)

cn <- c("FirstName", "LastName")
NAME <- as.character(tteam$NAME)

cbind( read.pattern(text = NAME, pattern = "^(\\S*) (.*)", col.names = cn), tteam[-1])
```

**Update** Update solution to be in terms of `tteam` and add second solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the package *unglue* :

```
library(unglue)
unglue_unnest(tteam, NAME, "{FirstName} {LastName}")
#>        TITLE FirstName     LastName
#> 1  assistant      John          Doe
#> 2    manager     Peter         Gynn
#> 3  assistant     Jolie Hope-Douglas
#> 4 specialist  Muhammad Arnab Halwai
```